# Not getting expected output while fetching data from firestore database

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

In my react native app, I want to display some items in home screen. The data of this items will be fetched from my Firestore Database. I have written the below code:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Frame } from 'react-native';
import firebase from "firebase"


export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state={
    items:null
  }
}

getItems(){
   const db = firebase.firestore()
   db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots : true})
   db.collection('dishes').get().then((snapshot)=>{
     snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
       let items = doc.data

       items = JSON.stringify(items)

       this.setState({items : items})
     })
   })
}

componentDidMount() {

   this.getItems()
}

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View>

               <Text>{ this.state.items || 'Loading' }</Text>
                
                </View>
                
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

But I am not getting any data.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: At first sight it appears that you call `this.setState` in the `forEach` loop so for each `DocumentSnapshot` present in the `QuerySnapshot`. You should build an array of items in the `forEach` loop and then, outside the loop, re-renders the component to the browser